# Get data out of array of dictionaries from JSON response

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary, swift3

I am trying to get data out of an array of nested dictionaries which is the result of a JSON response.

```
func fetchData() {
    let urlString = "https://global.api.pvp.net/api/lol/static-data/na/v1.2/champion?api_key=\(self.apiKey)"
    let url = URL(string: urlString)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error ?? "ERROR!")
        } else {
            do {

                let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String:Any]
                print(parsedData)
                print(parsedData["type"] ?? "")
                print(parsedData["version"] ?? "")

                print(type(of: parsedData))
                print(type(of: parsedData["data"]!))


                //ERROR HERE.
                //"Cannot subscript a value of type '[String, Any]' with an index of type '(String, (String, Any).Type)'
                let innerItem = parsedData["Aatrox", (String, Any)]





            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }

    }.resume()
```

Here is what is printed:

```
["type": champion, "version": 7.4.3, "data": {
Aatrox =     {
    id = 266;
    key = Aatrox;
    name = Aatrox;
    title = "the Darkin Blade";
};
Ahri =     {
    id = 103;
    key = Ahri;
    name = Ahri;
    title = "the Nine-Tailed Fox";
};
Akali =     {
    id = 84;
    key = Akali;
    name = Akali;
    title = "the Fist of Shadow";
};
Alistar =     {
    id = 12;
    key = Alistar;
    name = Alistar;
    title = "the Minotaur";
};
}]

champion
7.4.3

Dictionary<String, Any>
__NSDictionaryI
```

I am trying to get the "id" for "Aatrox".

How would i go about doing this?
is it because the type of parsedData["data"]! is __NSDictionaryI??

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to extract `data` Dictionary then access other dictionary.

```
do {
    let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! [String:Any]
    if let passDic = parsedData["data"] as? [String:Any],
       let innerItem = passDic["Aatrox"] as? [String: Any] {
          print(innerItem)
    }

} catch  {
     print(error)
}
```

Comment: @Changerrs Welcome mate :) You can also loop through the passDic to access all the nested dictionary.

Comment: thanks brotha, i wasnt telling the compiler that parsed["data"] is of type (not sure im saying this correctly) [String:Any]. This was the part i was missing.

Comment: @Changerrs It happens, Welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it should be `let innerItem: [String: Any] = parsedData["Aatrox"]`

Comment: hmmm.. a little closer. it is compiling. but crashes at runtime  

fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value  

parsedData has 3 items, [type, version, data]

should i be doing something like?:  
let innerItem: [String: Any] = parsedData["data"]["Aatrox"]

Comment: You have to extract the `parsedData["data"]` into another dict first then use it with this

Comment: var newDataDict = parsedData["data"]
let innerItem: [String: Any] = newDataDict["Aatrox"]

still getting error: "Type 'Any?' has no subscript memebers"

Comment: `var newDataDict: [String:Any]` should work, you have to specify the type for it :D

Answer (score 0):

```
let data : [string:Any] = parsedData.value(key: "data")
let aatrox : [string:Any] = data["Aatrox"]
print("**id**\(aatrox["id"])")
```

this thing work for me..